# Inverse of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Consider  the following tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix. Let $n$ be even.
$${A_{n \times n}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0}&{1}&{}&{}&{}\\
{1}&{0}&{1}&{}&{}\\
{}&{1}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{}\\
{}&{}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{1}\\
{}&{}&{}&{1}&{0}
\end{array}} \right]$$
What is the inverse $A^{-1}$?

Clearly, $A^{-1}$ is symmetric.

I look for a proof of the following *conjecture* that $A^{-1}$ is given as follows:

If $A_{i, j}^{-1}$ such that $j$ is odd and $i =1+j + 2 m$ with $m\in \cal N_0$, then $A_{i, j}^{-1} = (-1)^m$. From which follows by symmetry:

If $A_{i, j}^{-1}$ such that $j$ is even and $i =-1+j - 2 m$ with $m\in \cal N_0$, then $A_{i, j}^{-1} = (-1)^m$.

All other $A_{i, j}^{-1} = 0$.

Here is an example, computed with Matlab, for $n=10$ which shows the structure:

$${A_{10 \times 10}^{-1}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &      0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &      0 &     1 \\
     1 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
     0 &     0 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1  \\
    -1 &      0 &     1 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &      0 &     1 \\
     1 &     0 &    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1  \\
    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     0 &     1 \\
     1 &     0 &    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 &    -1 &     0 &     1 &     0 
\end{array}} \right]$$

Comment: You might try the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. $A^{-1}$ can be written as a polynomial in $A$ and with some ingenuity you may be able to figure out the coefficients.

Comment: Can you give us an example for $n$ being odd too?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz The questions says $n$ even. For $n$ odd,  as far as I see it, $\det(A)=0$ so no inverse exists. You may want to prove this as well ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to establish the conjecture is to perform the multiplication $E = A^{-1} A$ with the conjectured $A^{-1}$ and show that the result is the unit matrix. Since $A$ is bi-diagonal, each entry of $E$ is the sum of at most two terms, so there is little confusion.

$$E_{ik} = \sum_{j=1}^n A^{-1}_{ij} A_{j k} = A^{-1}_{ij} A_{j, j-1} \delta_{j-1,k} + A^{-1}_{ij} A_{j, j+1} \delta_{j+1,k}\\
= A^{-1}_{i, k+1} A_{k+1, k}  + A^{-1}_{i, k-1} A_{k-1, k} \\
= A^{-1}_{i, k+1}   + A^{-1}_{i, k-1} $$

Now the diagonal is 
$$E_{ii} 
= A^{-1}_{i, i+1}   + A^{-1}_{i, i-1} $$
From the structure of $A^{-1}$, if $i$ is odd, then $A^{-1}_{i, i+1}  = 1 $ and $ A^{-1}_{i, i-1} = 0 $. If $i$ is even, then $A^{-1}_{i, i+1}  = 0 $ and $ A^{-1}_{i, i-1} = 1 $. So in all cases, $E_{ii} = 1$.

For $k \ne i $, i.e the off-diagonal terms, we have $E_{ik} = A^{-1}_{i, k+1}   + A^{-1}_{i, k-1} $. From the structure of  $A^{-1}$, either both of these summands are zero, or one is $+1$ and the other $-1$, as we have values of $(-1)^m$ for an index difference of $2m$. Hence, always $E_{ik} =0$.

This completes the proof. $\qquad \Box$

Answer (score 5):

Firstly Matrix is Toeplitz. This means it represents multiplication by power series expansion. This means matrix inversions corresponds to multiplicative inversion

Therefore, consider $$x+x^{-1}=\frac{x^2+1}x$$ Now it's multiplicative inverse:

$$(x+x^{-1})^{-1}=\frac x{x^2+1}$$

Now you can expand with geometric series / Taylor expansion for $$\frac 1{x^2+1}=\frac 1{1-(-1\cdot x^2)}$$
And substitute with
$$\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+\cdots, t=-x^2$$
and then finish. You will notice the flipping sign pattern and that the odd exponents disappear when you substitute and do the expansion.

Comment: Good point! How does this explain the negative exponents? I.e . $\frac x{x^2+1} = x^{-1}\frac 1{1+ x^{-2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^{(-2 k-1)}$ would be the expansion for $|x|>1$ but can you simply augment these coefficients to the inverse Toeplitz matrix?  

And another question: how does this power series expansion explain that for odd $n$, no inverse exists? 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andreas I tried making the explanation better.

Comment: Thanks for extending you text. However (please have a look at the question text and the example again) your expansion only gives the correct matrix entries for $i>j$. For $i<j$ one could generate entries by the symmetry condition $A_{i j}^{-1} = A_{j i}^{-1}$ or by the expansion I gave in my previous comment. However, I wonder if this "augmenting" is the only way to handle it, or if there is a more principled way.  And another question remains: how does this power series expansion explain that for an $n \times n$-Matrix $A$ with odd $n$, no inverse exists? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found an algorithm that I hope it help you. Let the inverse be$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1&c_2&\cdots&c_n\end{bmatrix}$$In other words, $c_i$s are the columns of $A^{-1}$. We build the $c_i$s recursively as following:
$$c_{2}=e_1\\c_{2k+2}=-c_{2k}+e_{2k+1}\qquad,\qquad 1\le k\le {n\over 2}-1$$also $$c_{n-1}=e_n\\c_{2k-1}=e_{2k}-c_{2k+1}\qquad,\qquad 1\le k\le {n\over 2}-1$$where $e_i$s are the columns of $I_n$